# Selenium Java test with TFS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, tfs

Our Testers building Selenium integration test suite with Java+TestNG.
Our development team work with .Net and Team Foundation server.

Mainly b'cose their competencies are on those techs.

Questing is it possible to run java selenium tests through TFS ? basically could it possible to set up CI/CD environment? Or would be better-off go with same tech?

If is it possible, are there good tutorials that could be follow up.

Comment: TFS is an Project management tool where we can manage Test cases, Tasks, stories and even we can raise Defect too. But if you want to schedule your Selenium script which is used for CI/CD- for that you should try with different tool- i.e Git- for CI and Jenkins -for CD.

Comment: if urs using eclipse, plug is available for TFS integration.

Comment: @Bharat I don't understand why switch to Git? dev's already using TFS and huge code base is in it.

Comment: @Vel yes selenium are in eclipse for the moment will do more research, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your version of TFS is capable of using the TFS Marketplace (i.e. you have TFS2015 or above, or you are actually using VSTS), then yes, it's possible.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926119/tfs-and-testng-possible-to-execute-testng-tests-within-tfs2015) gives more information and some useful links.

The [TFS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts) has numerous plugins - the question I linked above shows how to use the Maven plugin to run TestNG tests.

(Disclaimer: I am not employed by Microsoft - I use TFS2017 at work)

Answer (score 0):

The type of technology and specific language does not change for two different processes, which means that the maintenance of any environment will involve people who are skilled in the same technology and/or language.